# Where are the Woodflies?

Tags: etrian-odyssey-untold

in the Quest *Subduing the Woodflies* i need to kill woodflies at a Take Spot. i would have assumed that i would get into a set encounter however i've checked the ones in A3 and B7 and neither have i faced woodflies.

The only place on *Emerald Grove / B2* that i have yet to explore is behind the door with the White Crystal in C3 however since the quest appeared before i have learned how to open those doors with the crystals i would have assumed it's doable.

I am wondering, where are these wood flies i have to kill or are they behind the White Crystal Door in C3?

Note: i don't want to know how to open the White Crystal door in C3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't be able to get into that crystal door for a while. Near the stairs leading down to floor 3 (So it's on floor 2 of the labyrinth) to the left there is a small indent to the north in the hall of A6. There should be an event in that small indent. Beware, as there is an encounter with the mini-boss Giant Woodfly, though he is far easier than any FOEs.